# Derivative with respect to inner function with differing inputs?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

There's a conceptual deal with derivatives of composite functions that I'm really struggling to understand.

- Let $g(t)$ be some continuous, differentiable function.
- $f(t) = g(t) + g(t + 1) + g(t^2)$

Now, $\frac{df}{dt}$ is trivial to solve with the chain rule. **What's $\frac{\bf df}{\bf dg}$?**

---

Naïvely, treating $g$ as just the input into $f$, it seems analogous to $\frac{d}{dx}(x+x+x) = 3$. But in the equation for $f$ above, it doesn't seem right that the three $g$ terms, which could all represent vastly different quantities for any given input, should have the same instantaneous rate of change. Is it really true that for an infinitesimal change to the output of $g$, the output of $f$ simply changes by 3 times as much, *for any value of x?*

Or am I wrong? Or am I asking a completely nonsensical question?

(For context, I'm working on some homebrewed alternative neural network structures, and I'm treating some neurons as compositions of functions. For error measurement purposes, it would be great to take derivatives of the outer functions with respect to the inner function alone.)

Comment: The question is not clear. Did you mean to write $(f(g))(t)$ rather than $f(g(t))$?

Comment: Your definition of $f(g(t))$ is not valid: Let e. g. be $g(t)=t^2$. So, think about what $f(1)$ is in this case. It turns out there are two possible answers: On the one hand, you have $f(1)=f(g(1))=g(1)+g(2)+g(1)=6$ but on the other hand you also get $f(1)=f(g(-1))=g(-1)+g(0)+g(1)=2$.

Comment: If you meant that the map is $g \mapsto f(g)$ is defined by $(f(g))(t) =\text{ the above}$, then $f$ is linear and in appropriate spaces is trivially differentiable.

Comment: @copper.hat Of course that wouldn't help for computing the derivative w.r.t to $t$ using the chain rule...

Comment: ${df \over dt}$ makes no sense with my interpretation, so I would reiterate that the question is far from clear.

Comment: @copper.hat My mistake! I got my notation switched up; hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comment section, your problem is a bit ambiguous / ill-defined. However, according to me, you can take two points of view, depending on whether you are interested in a local or global dependence between $f$ and $g$.

**1. Local variation**

If you want to find the local/instantaneous variation of the output $f$ due to the one of the input $g$, you can simply apply the following trick :
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}g} = \frac{\mathrm{d}f/\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}g/\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{g'(t) + g'(t+1) + 2tg'(t^2)}{g'(t)}
$$

**2. Global variation**

On the other hand, if you are interested in the global variation of $f$ due to $g$, in other words, if you want to study how $f$ changes when the whole function $g$ varies, then you need to consider $f$ as a functional and to take its functional derivative in consequence, as follows :
$$
\frac{\delta f(t)}{\delta g(\tau)} = \delta(t-\tau) + \delta(t+1-\tau) + \delta(t^2-\tau)
$$
where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta.

In the present case, you may consider the first case, since $f$ is somewhat defined locally (i.e. through a unique parameter $t$), even if it depends on the three different points $t$, $t+1$ and $t^2$. However, you might construct other models for your neural network in the future, where the dependence of $f$ on $g$ will be based on more points (or even on all the points, through integration for instance), so that you might need to study it non-locally as in the second case.

Comment: Thank you—this math *is*, in fact, a bit over my head, but knowing that they're isn't a simple, intro-calc-level solution is actually quite helpful for my work. So sorry again for the ambiguity!